Understanding lisp in the law of demeter paper
The law of Demeter paper contains snippets of some version of Lisp. Since I do not know Lisp I went ahead and tried to get an overview of the syntax. However the Lisp in that paper seems to be an older version of Lisp and I've trouble understanding those snippets.
Here is the paper
Here is the first snippet at the end of page 4
(defmethod (A :bad-style)()
  (send (send (send-self :first)
    :sixth) :seventh)) 

Could someone help me translate this to a more common language like Dart, typescript, java,...  ?
Here is the second snippet from page 5:
;A = <x> B.
(defmethod (A :alias) (t)
  (send self :set-x (send t :x)))
;T = <x> B.
(defmethod (T :m2) (a)
  (send (send a :x) :m3)) 


That's the Flavors object system.

The paper itself says "Lisp/Flavors" in many places.

"Currently the Demeter system “sits on top of” Old-Flavors and so the methods are written in the Lisp/Old-Flavors notation. "

It's just message passing. (send a :x) invokes the method :x on object a.

Here are links to a couple of papers about Flavors and Demeter that might be of interest.

@adabsurdum I've found this one that explains the language a bit https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/nnnfla1-20040122.pdf
